# incorrect Oracle order calculation logic at the query level

Tags: sql, oracle

With online qty and str qty, I'm having trouble calculating the quantity.

I tried the data computation with one record, and it worked perfectly with online qty and str qty. However, when I attempted it with several records (same items), it did not work. I need guidance on this.
I've written the following query, so if I'm wrong on how to design the select statement or if somebody is utilising the cursor approach, please give specifics.

**Query :**

```
with final_order as (
select 121212 po,11111 item ,20 sw_need,30 order_det from dual union all
select 131313 po,22222 item ,50 sw_need,30 order_det from dual union all
select 141414 po,33333 item ,50 sw_need,40 order_det from dual union all
select 151515 po,33333 item ,50 sw_need,30 order_det from dual union all
select 161616 po,44444 item ,50 sw_need,40 order_det from dual union all
select 171717 po,44444 item ,50 sw_need,5 order_det from dual)
select item, 
case 
when sw_need<order_det then sw_need
when sw_need>order_det then order_det-1
else 0
end online_qty,
case 
when sw_need<order_det then order_det-sw_need
when sw_need>order_det then (order_det) -(order_det-1)
else 0
end str_qty
from final_order
```

**Query results**

| ITEM | ONLINE_QTY | STR_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11111 | 20 | 10 |
| 22222 | 29 | 1 |
| 33333 | 39 | 1 |
| 33333 | 29 | 1 |
| 44444 | 39 | 1 |
| 44444 | 4 | 1 |

**Expected results**

| PO | ITEM | SW_NEED | ORDER_DET | ONLINE_QTY | STORE_QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 121212 | 11111 | 20 | 30 | 20 | 10 |
| 131313 | 22222 | 50 | 30 | 29 | 1 |
| 141414 | 33333 | 50 | 40 | 40 | 0 |
| 151515 | 33333 | 50 | 30 | 10 | 20 |
| 1616416 | 44444 | 50 | 40 | 40 | 0 |
| 171717 | 44444 | 50 | 5 | 4 | 1 |

Comment: Imagine you stumbled over this question. What would you say? What would be your answer? Can you read it? I can't, it is unformatted. Do you know what's wrong with it? I don't; you just said "it did not work". What does that mean? Did you get any error? If so, which one? Your "expected result" seems to be nothing but sample data (I presume); how is that "expected result"? I suggest you edit the question and make it readable and understandable.

Comment: Presumably it 'works perfectly' for the `case when` calculations; and not for the `else` ones. The second `else` certainly looks wrong - `(order_det) -(order_det-1)` is always going to be exactly 1 (unless `order_det` is null). I would *guess* that you tried to base that calculation on the `order_qty` and got an invalid0identity error, but it's hard to tell. You need to think about, and clearly explain, what you want those calculations to actually do - in plain English before you try to convert it to SQL.

Comment: Expected output is contradictory: po's 131313 and 151515 both have 50 and 30 as input, but have different output. What is the logic to calculate the result?